# Poner Alert de confirmacion en este codigo

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hola alguien me podria ayudar como colocar un alert que primero me diga si desea confirmar si o no en este codigo

ESTE ES MI JAVASCRIPT

```
 function Fagregartecins_inc_67(){
        //alert("Incumplió rta1");
            tec_inc_id_tecnicos_67 = $('#txt_tec_ins_inc_67 ').val();
            tec_inc_id_pregunta_67 = 67 //$('#txt_tec_inc_id_pre_2').val();
            if(tec_inc_id_tecnicos_67 == '' || tec_inc_id_tecnicos_67    == null){
                alert('Debe seleccionar un técnico.');
                return;
            }

            var datosTecInc1 = {
                    tec_inc_id_tecnicos         : tec_inc_id_tecnicos_67,
                    tec_inc_id_pregunta         : tec_inc_id_pregunta_67
                };

            //alert("agregando tecnico..."  + tec_inc_id_tecnicos_1); 
            $.post('php/agregartecinc.php', datosTecInc1, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    //alert("Procesando...");
                    if (data == 0){
                        alert('No se pudo procesar. Intente mas tarde.');
                        return;
                    }
                    if (data == 2){
                        alert('No se ha ingresado el técnico a la inspeccion.');
                        return;
                    }
                    if (data == 3){
                        alert('No se pudo procesar. Error al insertar.');
                        return;
                    }
                    if (data == 5){
                        alert('Cedula de tecnico no encontrada.');
                        return;
                    }
                    if (data == 1){
                        //alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el registro: ' + data);
                        alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el registro.');
                        $.post('php/cuadrilla_actualiza.php', datosTecInc1, function(data2, textStatus, xhr) {
                            //alert(data2);
                            $('#datoscuadrilla').html(data2);
                        });
                        return;
                    }
                    alert('Error:' + data);

            }); 
        return;
    }
```

y mi insert

```
$tec_inc_id_tecnicos        = addslashes($_POST['tec_inc_id_tecnicos']);
$tec_inc_id_pregunta        = addslashes($_POST['tec_inc_id_pregunta']);
//echo $tec_inc_id_tecnicos . '_' .$tec_inc_id_pregunta;
//die();
if (!empty($_POST)){ 
        if ($_SESSION['id_contrato'] == null or $_SESSION['id_contrato'] == '' or $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] == null or $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] == ''){ 
            echo 2; //No se tiene variable id_contrato/id_inspeccion
            //die();
        }
        else {
            //echo 1;

            // cedula tecnico
            $sql_tec = "SELECT 
                id_tecnicos
            FROM 
                tecnicos
            WHERE
                cedula = '$tec_inc_id_tecnicos';";

            $con = Conectar();
            $resultado_tec = $con->query($sql_tec);

            /* Recuperar y almacenar en conjunto los resultados de la consulta.*/
            $idx = 0;

            $Resultados_tec = array();

            while ($row_tec = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_tec)) {
                $Resultados_tec[$idx] = array();
                $Resultados_tec[$idx]['id_tecnicos']    = utf8_encode($row_tec['id_tecnicos']);
                $idx++;
            }
            if ( $idx == 0){
                echo 5;
                die();
            } 

            // fin cedula tecnico
            $sql =   "INSERT INTO  tecnico_incumplimientos (id_tecnicos , id_pregunta,id_inspeccion) 
                            VALUES (".$Resultados_tec[0]['id_tecnicos'].",".$tec_inc_id_pregunta."," .$_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] .")";
            $con = Conectar();

            $con->query(utf8_decode($sql));

            if ( $con->affected_rows > 0){
                $nuevoId = $con->insert_id;
                echo 1;
                //echo $nuevoId;
            } 
            else{
                echo 3 . $sql;
            }
        }
}
else{ 
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: Especifica donde exactamente quieres añadir la alerta de confirmación

Comment: Yo uso SweetAlert https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/ podes vericar el ejemplo de pedido de ok antes de cancelar

Comment: @HamzaAkiour lo quisiera colocar antes de que diga Se ha guardado correctamente el registro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes emplear el `confirm()`, te voy a colocar un ejemplo corto y luego lo introduzco en tu código **JS**:

```js
function myFunction() {
  if(confirm("Desea guardar los datos?")){
    alert("Datos guardados exitosamente");
  }else{
    alert("Usted cancelo la acción para guardar");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Probar</button>
```

**Con tu código JS:**

```js
function Fagregartecins_inc_67(){
  
  if(confirm("Deseas guardar los datos?")){
  
            tec_inc_id_tecnicos_67 = $('#txt_tec_ins_inc_67 ').val();
            tec_inc_id_pregunta_67 = 67 //$('#txt_tec_inc_id_pre_2').val();
            if(tec_inc_id_tecnicos_67 == '' || tec_inc_id_tecnicos_67    == null){
                alert('Debe seleccionar un técnico.');
                return;
            }

            var datosTecInc1 = {
                    tec_inc_id_tecnicos         : tec_inc_id_tecnicos_67,
                    tec_inc_id_pregunta         : tec_inc_id_pregunta_67
                };

            //alert("agregando tecnico..."  + tec_inc_id_tecnicos_1); 
            $.post('php/agregartecinc.php', datosTecInc1, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    //alert("Procesando...");
                    if (data == 0){
                        alert('No se pudo procesar. Intente mas tarde.');
                        return;
                    }
                    if (data == 2){
                        alert('No se ha ingresado el técnico a la inspeccion.');
                        return;
                    }
                    if (data == 3){
                        alert('No se pudo procesar. Error al insertar.');
                        return;
                    }
                    if (data == 5){
                        alert('Cedula de tecnico no encontrada.');
                        return;
                    }
                    if (data == 1){
                        //alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el registro: ' + data);
                        alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el registro.');
                        $.post('php/cuadrilla_actualiza.php', datosTecInc1, function(data2, textStatus, xhr) {
                            //alert(data2);
                            $('#datoscuadrilla').html(data2);
                        });
                        return;
                    }
                    alert('Error:' + data);

            }); 
        return;
       }
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="Fagregartecins_inc_67()">Probar</button>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) el cual:

> Muestra una ventana de diálogo con un mensaje opcional y dos botones,
>   Aceptar y Cancelar.

Por ejemplo:

```js
if (window.confirm("¿Realmente quieres realizar esta acción?")) {
  console.log("Aquí todo lo relativo a Sí");
} else {
  console.log("Aquí todo lo relativo a No");
}
```

---

#### Ejemplo de uso en tu código

```
                if (data == 1){
                    //alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el registro: ' + data);
                    alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el registro.');

                   if (window.confirm("¿Quieres lanzar el post?")) {
                        $.post('php/cuadrilla_actualiza.php', datosTecInc1, function(data2, textStatus, xhr) {
                        //alert(data2);
                        $('#datoscuadrilla').html(data2);
                    });
                   } else {
                        console.log("Dijiste que no cancelando");
                   }
```

---

### Mucha atención a esto

Es interesante lo que dice la nota [sobre este método en MDN en la sección **`Notas`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm#Notes) :

> Las cajas de diálogo son ventanas modales - ello impide al usuario
>   continuar accediendo al resto del interfaz del programa hasta que la
>   ventana modal haya sido cerrada. Por esta razón no se debería usar en
>   exceso funciones que creen cajas de diálogo (o ventanas modales). No
>   obstante, hay muy buenas razones para [evitar el uso de cajas de
>   diálogo para confirmaciones](http://alistapart.com/article/neveruseawarning).
>
> Los usuarios de [Mozilla Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Chrome) users (e.g. Firefox extensions)
>   deberían usar métodos de `nsIPromptService` en vez de cajas de
>   diálogo.
>
> A partir de la versión 46.0 de Chrome este método es bloqueado dentro
>   de un  a no ser que el atributo sandbox tenga el valor
>   allow-modal.
>
> El argumento es opcional y no requerido por la especificación.

Los cuadros de diálogo se usan cada vez menos en programación.

Comment: Hola amigo A. Cedano como te encuentras amigo la verdad es que no sabria como implantarlo a mi funcion soy muy novato en la programacion

Comment: @JSACTMMusic puse un ejemplo de cómo su usaría en el contexto de tu código, revisa la respuesta ahora editada.